# Meaning behind $\mathbf{V} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, notation

When I have a vector space spanned by a set of vectors:$$\mathbf{V}=\mathrm{span}\{(a,b,c,d)^T,(d,e,f,g)^T,(2a,2b,2c,2d)^T\},$$How can I write $\mathbf{V}$ in terms of a subset to another vector space? In this case $\mathbf{V}$ is a subspace of dimension 2, but is it true that it is also a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\mathbb{R}^4$, i.e. $\mathbf{V}\subset\mathbb{R}^3$, $\mathbf{V}\subset\mathbb{R}^4$?

My confusion is that when I write $\mathbf{V} \subset \mathbb{R}^3$, does it also imply the all of the element in $\mathbf{V}$ are triples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  $V\subset\mathbb R^4$.  But $V\not\subset\mathbb R^3$, here.

Though $V$ is $2$-dimensional,  it is a subspace of $\mathbb R^4$.  Vectors in $\mathbb R^4$ are expressed as $4$-tuples.

Whereas $\mathbb R^3$ "sits" in $\mathbb R^4$ in a fairly obvious way, we cannot say, for instance,  that any $2$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^4$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$.  If the fourth coordinate is $0$ for all elements of $V$, we can say that, in a sense, $V\subset \mathbb R^3$.  But here we would be thinking of $\mathbb R^3$ as the set of $4$-tuples with fourth coordinate $0$.  Note there are other $"\mathbb R^3"$s in $\mathbb R^4$ (let each of the other $3$ coordinates be $0$).

Plus there are lots of other there $3$-dimensional subspaces (one corresponding to each normal direction).

Btw, all $n$-dimensional vector spaces are isomorphic.

All this can take some getting used to.

Comment: So we can't simply use the notation $\mathbf{V} \subseteq  \mathbb{R}^n$ to say that the subspace $\mathbf{V}$ has n dimension, because its element might be of $(\geqslant n)$-tuples?

Comment: Right.  Any higher dimensional space has $n$-dimensional subspaces.

Answer (score 0):

No. For example , span of (1,1) in a plane is the line passes through the origin which makes an angle of 45 degree in each of the coordinate axes. It is one dimensional. But  considering the same set in a three dimensional space is meaningless.
Instead we consider span(1,1,0).

Comment: Does it mean I can only say $\mathrm{span} \{ (1,1)^T \} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, but not $\mathrm{span} \{ (1,1)^T \} \subset \mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: Yes. The second one is meaningless

Comment: I'm very confused with the notation, how do we represent a vector space $\mathbf{V}$ that is of dimension $n$, but having elements of m-tuples ? Like how do we represent $\mathbf{V}=\mathrm{span} \{(1,1,0,0)^T,(1,0,1,0)^T,(1,0,0,1)^T \}$? Do I just simply write it as $\mathbf{V} \in \mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: The vectors are in a four dimensional space so you can say V is a subset of a four dimensional space

Comment: I think I get it now, thank you!

Comment: @WeiShanNg If you want to say that a vector space consists of $m$-tuples, you can write $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$. That does not tell you the dimension of $V$, though (you only know it’s at most $m$). To say that $V$ has dimension $n$, write $\dim V = n$.